# Should I keep using the version of Flash in the sevenmachines PPA?

Tags: 10.04, flash

I've been running Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid) 64-bit for about one year now. Everything still seems to be working properly, but for the last two months, I've been getting this error message every time Update Manager runs:

> "Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/sevenmachines/flash/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
>   404  Not Found Some index files failed to download, they have been
>   ignored, or old ones used instead."

I did a bit of searching, and the best I can find is that Sevenmachines isn't supporting this software anymore and has deleted everything relating to it. I haven't been able to find anything discussing a new version or even how to get Synaptic/Update to stop looking for updates to this software. Most of what I've found dates to mid 2010 and is no longer current (in fact, most of what I've found is how to install the Sevenmachines version).

Should I keep running version `11.0.1.129-0ubuntu0~sevenmachines1`? If yes, how do I get Synaptic to stop looking for updates that no longer exist? If not, what software should I be installing to replace it and still keep Flash working?

Answer (score 2):

You can install flash from the Ubuntu repositories.

32 bit flash

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
```

64 bit flash is in the partners repository

You first need to activate the partners repository

[image: partners]

See : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Adding_Canonical_Partner_Repositories for details.

You then remove any 32 bit flash

```
sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-nonfree flashplugin-installer gnash gnash-common mozilla-plugin-gnash swfdec-mozilla
sudo rm -f /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/libflashplayer.so
sudo rm -f /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so
sudo rm -f /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so
sudo rm -f /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/npwrapper*flash*so
rm -f ~/.mozilla/plugins/*flash*so
```

Then install the 64 bit version

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

See [the ubuntu wiki flash page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AMD64/FirefoxAndPlugins#A64-bit_Firefox_and_64-bit_Flash_plugin) for details.

And you will also need to remove the sevenmachines PPA:

- [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

Comment: Why so complicated?

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install it manually. It's not that difficult.

1. Visit Adobes website: http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/.
2. Select "tar.gz for other Linux". Download that package.
3. Find it in your downloads directory, right click and extract it.
4. You'll get a file called libflashplugin.so.
5. Copy that file into .mozilla/plugins/ in your home directory.
6. Restart Firefox.

You can press ctrl+h to display hidden files. (Files and folders that begin with a period are hidden)

Comment: Or copy it to `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins` for all users - `sudo cp libflashlugin.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins`