# How do I install the latest Adobe Flash plugin on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: 10.04

I am a person who has absolutely no idea how Ubuntu works so I want to ask how do I install the latest version of Adobe Flash Player on 32-bit Ubuntu 10.04? I currently have installed Adobe Flash Player 10

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from the adobe website and install it from there.

Visit http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ and choose the `tar.gz for other Linux` extract it and copy the libflashplugin.so into your `$HOME/.mozilla/plugins/` folder.

There are also some other alternatives responded to this message here:
[Should I keep using the version of Flash in the sevenmachines PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92078/should-i-keep-using-the-version-of-flash-in-the-sevenmachines-ppa)

Comment: How do I add it to chrome? Sorry for the late reply!

Comment: You should install the pepperflashplugin-nonfree package, but its not available for 10.04. It may be available in a ppa though. You can try this: https://launchpad.net/~skunk/+archive/ubuntu/pepper-flash